# HttpWebResponse does not respond

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest, compact-framework, windows-ce, httpwebresponse

I've some issue with the `HttpWebRequest`. I'm trying to manage a connection between a server with a WebService and a Windows CE 6.0 with CF 2.0 client and my actual purpose is to retrieve the external IP of the Windows CE machine. I've tried to using the `HttpWebResponse` but it get stuck during a call. 
Now I'll be more clearly, that's the code that I'm running on the WinCE machine to get the IP:

```
    private string GetIPAddressRemote()
    {
        Uri validUri = new Uri("http://icanhazip.com");

        try
        {
            string externalIP = "";

            HttpWebRequest httpRequest = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(validUri);

            httpRequest.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
            httpRequest.Timeout = 10000;  // Just to haven't an endless wait

            using (HttpWebResponse httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpRequest.GetResponse()) 
            /* HERE WE ARE
             * In this point my program stop working... 
             * well actually it doesn't throw any exception and doesn't crash at all
             * For that reason I've setted the timeout property because in this part
             * it starts to wait for a response that doesn't come
             */
            {
                using (Stream stream = httpResponse.GetResponseStream())
                { 
                    // retrieve the return string and 
                    // save it in the externalIP variable
                }
            }

            return externalIP;
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            return ex.Message;
        }
    }
```

So, what's my problem? I don't know why it stucks during the `httpRequest.GetResponse()` call, any idea?
I've to say that I'm under a proxy, so I came up with the idea that maybe the proxy blocks some requests, could it be?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I came up with something like this:

```
    private string GetIPAddressRemote()
    {
        Uri validUri = new Uri("http://icanhazip.com/");

        int tryNum = 0;

        while (tryNum < 5)
        {
            tryNum++;

            try
            {
                string externalIP = "";

                WebProxy proxyObj = new WebProxy("http://myProxyAddress:myProxyPort/", true); // Read this from settings

                WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(validUri);

                request.Proxy = proxyObj;
                request.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
                request.Timeout = 10000;  // Just to haven't an endless wait

                using (WebResponse response = request.GetResponse())
                {
                    Stream dataStream = response.GetResponseStream();

                    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataStream))
                    {
                        externalIP = reader.ReadToEnd();
                    }
                }
                return externalIP;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                if(tryNum > 4)
                    return ex.Message;
            }

            Thread.Sleep(1000);
        }
        return "";
    }
```

But now the problem is that there aren't any information to retrieve. I mean, the string that I parse from the `Stream` is a `html` page and the string that retrieve is:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <h1>It works!</h1>
    <p>This is the default web page for this server.</p>
    <p>The web server software is running but no content has been added, yet.</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

What can I do now?

Comment: if your goal is to get the server IP address, you can try with hostname resolution thorugh a DNS. Otherwise you can easier execute a ping instead of a WebRequest and get the IP from there...

Comment: Nope, my goal is to get the IP of the machine that is connected to the server. Anyway now I'm trying an another route to get the connection between the machine and the server and also between the server and an another PC.